# How to check a string is present in an object or not in js?

Tags: javascript, string, object, search, filter

**Note: OP is asking how to improve their *working* code**

I want to check a `string.substring(1)` is present in an object or not. If it presents then return it from the object or else return empty. I have written the below pseudo code.

For example, if my string is `*Test Title`, I want to check this string without the first letter i.e. `string.substring(1)` is present in the given object with array value `title` here it is present. So we need to return  `Test Title`. If I pass `*Test1` since it is not present with `title` it should return `''`

```js
let string = '*Test Title'

let string1 = '*Test1'

let object = {
    "0": [
        "para",
        "WZYYoPd3ummvxQN0"
    ],
    "1": [
        "insertorder",
        "first"
    ],
    "2": [
        "lmkr",
        "1"
    ],
    "3": [
        "title",
        "Test Title"
    ],
    "4": [
        "para",
        "Test1"
    ],
}

const b = Object.entries(object)
  .filter(value => value[1])
let str = ''
const c = b.filter(a => a[1][0] === 'title')
if (c.length) {
  c.filter((key) => {
    key[1].filter((n) => {
      if (n != 'title' && n === string.substring(1)) {
        str = n;
      }
    })
  })
}
if (str === '') {
  console.log(string);
} else {
  console.log(str);
}
```

The code works correctly. I want to know is there any room for simplifying this? Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I've created a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) for you. Feel free to edit if anything is wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood it correctly, if the first element of the inside list is 'title' , then only you'll need to check for the `string` present.
So you can try this :

```
let str = '';
for(var key in obj) {
    if(obj[key][0] === "title") {
        str = obj[key][1] === string.substring(1) ? obj[key][1] : '';
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Tnx. Just one change. We need a break if it is a match.